# Some questions about the point of instantiation for template

Tags: c++, templates

Firstly, some standard's quoted passage

> If a template specialization X is referenced in a context that depends on a   template-parameter of some surrounding template Y, the given point of   instantation depends on the point of instantation of Y.
>   If X is a function template specialization, the point of instantiation is that of Y.
>   If X is a class template specialization, the point of instantiation is   immediately before the point of instantiation of Y.
>
> Otherwise, the given point of instantiation is tied to the location of the   namespace scope declaration/definition (D) which contains the statement  referring to X.
>   If X is a function template specialization, the point of instantiation is immediately after D.
>   If X is a class template specialization, the point of instantiation is immediately before D.

Some code here

```
#include <iostream>
template<int N>
struct state {
    friend auto call(state<N>);
};
template<int N>
struct add_state {
    friend auto call(state<N>) {
        return N;
    }
};
template<typename T, int N>
T show() {
    add_state<N> d;
    return T{};
}
template<typename T,int N>
class data {
public:
    T c = show<T,N>();
};
#1,#3,#2
int main() {
    data<int, 0> t;
    call(state<0>{});
}
```

So, according to the above rules, when instantiating class `data<int, 0>`, then the point of instantiation is at #1.

Then `show<T,N>` depends on template class data's template parameters. So the point of instantiation for `show<int,0>` is at #2.

Then `add_state<N>` depends on template function show's template parameters. So according to the rules, the point of instantiation for `add_state<0>` is at #3.

At #3 `auto call(state<0>)` has been defined, `call(state<0>{})` should be linked but in the fact, the compiler reports errors as follows:

clang:

```
main.cpp:24:2: error: function 'call' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
        call(state<0>{});
        ^
main.cpp:4:14: note: 'call' declared here
        friend auto call(state<N>);
                    ^
1 error generated.
```

g++:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:24:17: error: use of ‘auto call(state<0>)’ before deduction of ‘auto’
  call(state<0>{});
                 ^
```

Why? Does my understand about the point of instantiation has some mistakes?
If not, why does the compiler report these errors?

Comment: Since `show` is a function template, it reuses #1, and #3 precedes that.

Comment: Be warned: stateful metaprogramming has been [condemned](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118) by the committee.

Comment: A function template specialization also has a point of instantiation at the end of the translation unit [\[temp.point\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#8). If `show<int,0>` is instantiated at the end of your translation unit, the definition of `call(state<0>)` will be after the use in `call(state<0>{});`. [temp.point]/5 also forbids "*two different points of instantiation [to] give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule*", although I don't know whether this includes this scenario.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang compile it fine if you use a placeholder return type for `show` to force the instantiation of the body: https://godbolt.org/z/jEuQ_k

Comment: @DavisHerring yeah,#1 and #2 are the same poi

Comment: @uneven_mark  I changed the T to auto and tested it on my g++ and clang,On my g++'s enviroment it works fine ,clang does not and report the same error,g++ version is 7.4 and clang version is 6.0. Before change the return type ,the complier should be instantiating the define of function show when it is the form of "T show(){...}",why change the "T" to "auto" ,g++ agree?how the mess

Comment: @uneven_mark  template function can have multi point of instantiation,One depends on the context where needed to implicit instantiation and the onther is the end of translation unit

Comment: @jackX Yes and I think that this is the cause of your problem. But I don't understand the paragraph in the standard about multiple points of instantiation well enough to be confident about it. That's why I put a bounty on your question, so that someone more knowledgeable might explain.

Comment: @uneven_mark Ok,thanks for your bounty,We together wait the more better answers about this question :)

Comment: Here is my understand,we know template function have multi poi,and one is depend on the call of point and the other is at the end of unit translation?If the return type is "auto",the complier must generate the definition at #3 because the complier needs to decide the "auto" by return type,Now complier chose #3 to instantiate the definition, if not,the complier usually chose the end of translation unit to instantiate definition and here call is defined ,so in the main function no call can look up

Answer (score 2):

According to [[temp.inst]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#temp.inst-2), when a class template is implicitly instantiated, only the declaration of friends are instantiated:

> The **implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes** the implicit instantiation of the **declarations, but not of the definitions**, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member templates, and **friends**;

So at #3 `auto call(state<N>)` is only declared. Moreover, this declaration is not found by ordinary unqualified name look-up.

Nevertheless I do not think that it makes your code formaly ill-formed. Your code is so strange that it is possible that such a situation has never been thought about by standard commitee members or compiler implementers: usualy inline friend functions are defined in the class that makes the friend function visible through ADL (Argument Dependent Name Lookup). This is certainly also what excepects a compiler.

So at `call(state<0>{})` inside `main`, the declaration of `call` is found by ADL inside the definition of `state` and the compiler just don't think about looking for a potential definition of this function in the somehow unrelated class `add_state`. So it fails to deduce `auto`.

Comment: [\[temp.inst\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#temp.inst-4) says "*A function whose declaration was instantiated from a friend function definition is implicitly instantiated when it is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist.*" The declaration of the definition should have been instantiated from `add_state<0>`, so I think it should be instantiated on the reference in `main`. It [does work](https://godbolt.org/z/9HVQP_) if `add_state<0>` is directly implicitly instantiated beforehand. So I don't think that the definition itself is a problem.

Comment: @uneven_mark. Why do you think that `add_state<0> d;` requires the definition of `call` to exist?

Comment: I do not. I think `add_state<0>` instantiates the declaration of `call` into the global namespace by [temp.inst]/2, because it contains a friend definition of it. Then `call(state<0>{});` in `main` requires the function definition (after being found through ADL) and therefore by [temp.inst]/4 the function definition should be instantiated from the definition in `add_state<0>`. The assumption I make is that the declarations of `call` in `state<0>` and `add_state<0>` refer to the same function.

Comment: @uneven_mark So the difference of interpretation between you and me is due to the term *context* ([temp.inst]/4 * ... is referenced in a context ...*). For you it is the entire definition of main. For me a context is just a full-expression or less.

Comment: I am not sure I follow that distinction. Do you think the compiling example I linked is ill-formed? How exactly `add_state<0>` and `call(state<0>)` are referenced does not matter that much in my interpretation, as long as it is ordered properly. You could for example move `add_state<0> t;` before `main` or combine them into one full-expression: [works with instantiation through `add_state<...>` but not `data<int, ...>`](https://godbolt.org/z/XPCPRF)

Comment: @uneven_mark In fact context is defined. This is a term used in formal grammar (or other mathematic area), it is the set of introduced name at the point where the compiler is. With my understanding only the declaration of `call` is introduced in the context by `add_state<0>`. So I suppose the code should not compile, even in the case you linked, this is my opinion. On the other hand, one could think that the fact that the definition of `call` can be found in the definition of `add_state` should be introduced in the context..., I think this is your opinion.

Comment: @uneven_mark Conclusion: I do believe you are in a really border case, not taken into acount in the standard. It may be preferable to leave this gray area because if you find a way to make your code compile, it is possible that at a compiler update breaks your code.

Comment: Yes, I guess that sums up my position, but I certainly don't know what the "correct" interpretation is and it is also clear that whatever the "correct" behavior is, it is not intended to be used in this way (as Davis Herring warned in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too confident myself in this matter, but in hope that this might prove useful I put together another working example, other than the ones already suggested:

```
#include <iostream>

// forward declaration of the
// add_state template
template<int>
struct add_state;


template<int N>
struct state {
    // Note: we generate the state here
    // so that the compiler will see the
    // definition of the call function
    add_state<N> t;
    friend auto call(state<N>);
};
template<int N>
struct add_state {
    friend auto call(state<N>) {
        return N;
    }
};


int main() {
    auto val = call(state<42>{});
    std::cout << val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this will help. But I hope so, as I, too would be interested in a good explanation.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, it always works if there are only class template specializations and no function template specializations in the instantiation sequence, which is why I assume that the special rule about instantiation points of function templates is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
template<int N>
struct state {
    friend auto call(state<N>);//<--no way of telling return type !
};
```

The compiler has absolutely no way of telling of what the `call` functions returns and has to give up.
The fix is obvious as well, just give it something to work with, eg.:

```
friend auto call(state<N>) {return N;}
```

Comment: I don't think that is the question. (@jackX please correct me.) Obviously it will work if the definition is provided directly. But it is generally completely fine to provide a declaration with placeholder return type and define it later, as long as the definition happens before the return type is required. The definition inside `add_state<0>` refers to the same function and should be instantiated (and return type deduced) when it is required from `call(state<0>{});`, assuming the declarations inside `add_state<0>` had already be instantiated.

Comment: You can see that the return type is not the issue by replacing it with some fixed type in both declarations. The program will then fail with a linker error instead. And there will also be no error if `add_state<0>` is explicitly instantiated before the call. (either with placeholder in the return type or not)

Comment: @uneven_mark  yes,you are right ,the purpose for template class state is to generate the declartion of call and  template class add_state is to generate the definition of call,adl can look up the call in class  state,if the definition excited,then call function will be linked

Comment: @uneven_mark In addition,I have given the explantion  in the comment under the question

Answer (score -2):

If used `int` instead of `auto` got error:

```
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `call(state<0>)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When added `{return N;}` to `friend int call(state<N>)`, worked fine.
Then replaced back `int` to `auto`, it also works.

Comment: add {return N ;} to which call?do you change the declartion of function call to the defination?